# How can I apply new trunk patches into a branch without applying older ones?

Tags: svn, merge, branch

Suppose I created a branch at revision 2 and I want to apply the changes made to the trunk in the revision 5 to the branch. How to do that while ignoring changes from revisions 3 and 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a .patch file from revision 5 and then apply that to your branch.  However, you need to make sure that none of the changes in revision 5 are dependent on revisions 3 and 4.

Comment: What will happen when I finally apply all trunk changes into the branch? Will SVN detect that I already applied revision 5 patch?

Comment: Yes it will, it will see that the revision 5 code already matches the patch file and would ignore it.  But since it would be the same anyway, it wouldnt matter.  This would only be a conflict if you change the code from revision 5 on the branch and then try to patch to the full trunk version.  (So the revision 5 code needs to stay the same on the branch)This would cause a conflict which you would have to resolve before merging them.